# Resetting Qt Style Sheet

Tags: qt, stylesheet, signals-slots

I've managed to style my QLineEdit to something like this:

[alt text http://www.kimag.es/share/54278758.png](http://www.kimag.es/share/54278758.png)

```
void Utilities::setFormErrorStyle(QLineEdit *lineEdit)
{
    lineEdit->setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #FF8A8A;"
            "background-image: url(:/resources/warning.png);"
            "background-position: right center;"
            "background-repeat: no-repeat;"
            "");
}
```

I called the function using

```
Utilities *util = new Utilities;
util->setFormErrorStyle(lineNoStaf);
```

The flow should be something like this:

1. User open form
2. User fill data
3. User submit data
4. Got error
5. Use `setFormErrorStyle()`
6. User edit the text in the **QLineEdit** and the style disappear

This function should be reusable over and over again, but how can I connect **QLineEdit** signal such as `textChanged()` to a function in other class that will reset the Style Sheet and then disconnect the signal so that it won't be running continuously every time the text changed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright, this is not compile but should work in principle, you should be able to change the look by calling `editWidget->setProperty('isError',true)` or `editWidget->setError(false)`

```
class ErrorTextEdit : QLineEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QPROPERTY(bool isError, READ isError, WRITE setError);

public:
  ErrorTextEdit(QWidget* parent) : QLineEdit(parent), m_isError(false)
  {
    m_styleSheet = "" // see below
    setStyleSheet(m_styleSheet);
  }

  void setError(bool val)
  {
     if (val != m_isError)
     {
       m_isError = val;
       setStyleSheet(m_styleSheet);
     }
  }

  bool isError() {return m_isError;}

private:
  QString m_styleSheet;
  bool m_isError;
}
```

for the stylesheet

```
ErrorTextEdit[isError="false"]
{
   optional ...
   Style for textedit that is NOT an error
}

ErrorTextEdit[isError="true"]
{
   background-color: #FF8A8A;
   background-image: url(:/resources/warning.png);
   background-position: right center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

the term

```
[<property>="<value>"]
```

restricts the application of the stylesheet to instances of the class whose `<property>` has the appropriate `<value>` the only caveat is that the style is *not* changed when the property changes its' value, so the stylesheet has to be reapplied for the look of the widget to actually change, see [Stylesheet Documentation -> Property Selector](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/stylesheet-syntax.html)

This construction moves the stylesheet into the widget that uses it and makes switch internal to the widget, the widget changes in accordance to its state.

In general you have a couple of ways to handle invalid inputs in your form

a) observe every change and update the style appropriately, you should be able to use [`QValidator`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qvalidator.html) for that too, but that is a separate topic, using QValidator you will probably be able to completely internalize the state of a single QTextEdit and not have to deal with its validity from the outside

b) Do it in the submit loop that you have described above, whenever the user clicks on submit change the state of the correct and incorrect fields

it all depends the structure of your app and the view

Answer (score 6):

Qt also allows dynamic properties in its stylesheet, that means you don't need to code your own class for every widget type in your form.

From http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

**Customizing Using Dynamic Properties** 
There are many situations where we need to present a form that has mandatory fields. To indicate to the user that the field is mandatory, one effective (albeit esthetically dubious) solution is to use yellow as the background color for those fields. It turns out this is very easy to implement using Qt Style Sheets. First, we would use the following application-wide style sheet:

```
 *[mandatoryField="true"] { background-color: yellow }
```

This means that every widget whose mandatoryField Qt property is set to true would have a yellow background.
Then, for each mandatory field widget, we would simply create a mandatoryField property on the fly and set it to true. For example:

```
 QLineEdit *nameEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
 nameEdit->setProperty("mandatoryField", true);

 QLineEdit *emailEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
 emailEdit->setProperty("mandatoryField", true);

 QSpinBox *ageSpinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
 ageSpinBox->setProperty("mandatoryField", true);
```

Works also in Qt 4.3!

Comment: Check the [limitations](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets) you also might need to use `.update()`

Answer (score 0):

See, the other idea is you need to override the paint evet of line edit and then set the background image and color.

here the implimentation is presetn [here](http://qt-articles.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-customize-button-in-qt.html)  button, follow up the same to your line edit

Comment: I don't have any problem in customizing the `QLineEdit`, but I'm having problem resetting it back using another function in different classes.

Comment: can you write a quick sample class and post the code.
you write the two class and tell in which scenario you are facing problem, it will be easy to track and find solution.

i am not getting, how exactly you want.